# The probability distribution of the number of coin flips needed to get $n$ heads or $k$ tails

Tags: probability

Suppose we are flipping a fair coin. Let n,k be fixed numbers. We flip the coin until we get a total of n heads or a total of k tails. What is the probability distribution of the number of coin flips needed to get n heads or k tails? If it is easier, what is the expectation? The support of this discrete distribution is from the min(n,k) to n+k-1.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of getting the $n$-th head on the $r$-th toss,
is that of the $r$-th toss being a head, and exactly $n-1$ of the first
$r-1$ tosses being heads, that is $p_r=
2^{-r}\binom{r-1}{n-1}$. In this case
this probability is only relevant if $r-n<k$. There is a similar
formula for the probability that the $k$-th tail occurs on the
$r$-th toss, that is $q_r=2^{-r}\binom{r-1}{k-1}$. So the probability
you seek is $p_r+q_r$ if $n\le r<k+n$ and $k\le r<k+n$, is $p_r$
if $n\le r<k+n$ and $k>r$ and is $q_r$ if
if $k\le r<k+n$ and $r>k$.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is right. Is there a name for this distribution? I want to find a closed form for its expectation. Also, is there a way to find a multinomial version. By that I mean instead of a coin flip, we can have a roll of a die. We stop if we get k1 ones, or k2 twos etc until k6 sixes. It is probably elementary to figure it all out, but I was wondering if it had a name so that I can lookup properties, asymptotics etc. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a negative binomial distribution.

Suppose that $X \sim NegBin(r;p)$

The probability mass function is given as

$$f(k;r,p) \equiv Pr(X=k) = \binom{k+r-1}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{r} $$

where $k$ is the number of successes and $r$ is the number of failures with probability $p$

We have

$$E(X) = \frac{r}{p} $$

In your specific case we have

$$ X \sim NegBin(k;p) $$

Then our mass function is
$$f(n;k,p) \equiv Pr(X=n) = \binom{n+k-1}{n}p^{n}(1-p)^{k} $$

where we have $n$ heads and $k$ tails. 
Given that you said it was fair $p =\frac{1}{2}$

$$f(n;k,p) \equiv Pr(X=n) = \binom{n+k-1}{n}(\frac{1}{2})^{n}(\frac{1}{2})^{k} $$
$$f(n;k,p) \equiv Pr(X=n) = \binom{n+k-1}{n}(\frac{1}{2})^{n+k}$$
$$f(n;k,p) \equiv Pr(X=n) = \binom{n+k-1}{n}2^{-(n+k)}$$

Comment: There is no $n$ in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is not negative binomial because we stop either when we get n ones or k zeros.

Comment: Ahh that is unfortunate..